# Best way to structure a gallery (Firestore)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to work out the best way to store a gallery in Cloud Firestore.

Each document will have it's own gallery.

**Firestore Structure:**

```
Collection
  - Document
    - Title
    - Gallery
```

The Flutter App will look like this:

**Screen 1:** List = [View Document button]

**Screen 2 (document):** [View Gallery Button]

**Screen 3:** [View Exterior images Button] [View Interior images button]

**Screen 4:** Display images depending on selection

These are my options so far:

1. Store image URLs in a map in each document (With this method, images are instantly available upon loading a document. My concern though is the size of each document, which will increase loading time of Screen 1)
2. Store image URLs in a sub-collection of each document (Will this result in an additional query to retrieve the gallery images?)
3. Store image URLs in another document in a "Galleries" collection that then contains a reference field to the main document (My concern with this is that there are then two queries to Firestore which require a second loading time when viewing gallery).

*Additionally: Is removing the base URL of Firestore Storage URLs to reduce document size a good idea? (ie, remove https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test.appspot.com/ (use only remainder of URL in document field) and insert it programmatically when called)*

Which method would be the most advantageous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, solution one is the one you can go ahead with but only as long you are 100% sure, that the size of the document does not exceed the limitation. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but as your map that contains the urls getts bigger, be careful about this limitation.

If you think that a single document getts bigger than the limitation, solution two is the one that will solve your problem.

> Additionally: Is removing the base URL of Firestore Storage URLs to reduce document size a good idea?

Yes it as. As explained above, you'll reduce the size of the document. Because that url:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test.appspot.com/
```

Is always a constant, you can use it in your code the recreate the entire url client side.